# Creating a RAID 0 on C drive

Tags: windows-10, raid, raid-0

The 250Gb SSD I am currently using on my C drive is starting to be full. I am considering buying a second one and make a RAID 0 to expand capacity (performance gain is just a bonus for me).

Is it possible to create a RAID 0 with the C drive without having to reinstall the system or anything like that.

I do not use the C drive for data storage, only for some programs I use every day. I store all my data in another hard drive.

I am also aware that if 1 drive in a RAID 0 fail, I lose everything.

Comment: You may want to do a little research into this before doing it though... There is almost zero gain in normal desktop usage between a SSD and a RAID-0 with 2 SSD drives. You would be better off considering NVMe, just using a new SSD as a second drive, or just a bigger single SSD drive

Comment: I dont really care about performance gain. My goal is simply to have a bigger storage on my C drive without having having to pay for a more expensive SSD

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

You will have to wipe the existing SSD to build the RAID 0 array. However, you can clone your SSD to a separate storage device, wipe the SSD, build the array, then finally clone the cloned drive to the new array.